# Undefined property: stdClass::$profession

Tags: api, laravel-5.4, guzzle

I am getting an error exception when trying to access an api.  I seem to be able to access all the columns in the api except the profession field.  Below is my code in the view.

```
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($teachers as $teacher)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$teacher->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$teacher->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$teacher->address}}</td>
        <td>{{$teacher->profession}}</td>
      </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

I have written a teacher controller which has the following code.

```
public function getAllTeachers()
{
   $teachers = $this->obtainAllStudents();

  return view('teachers.all-teachers', ['teachers' => $teachers]);
}
```

This inherits from a ClientController which as the following function to retrieve all the data for the teachers.

```
protected function obtainAllTeachers()
 {
     return      $this>performGetRequest('https://lumenapi.juandmegon.com/teachers');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using this:

```
$teachers = $this->obtainAllStudents();
```

instead of this:

```
$teachers = $this->obtainAllTeachers();
```